# Why my pageviews count on Google Analytics vs Adwords doesn't fit?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

Since the beginning of my Adwords campaign, every visit are perfectly calculated in my Google Analytics account. However, if I look up my Adwords visitor clicks (~1250) and my GA inbound visits (~250), they are not fitting at all.

My Analytics code (ga.js) is located at the end of my `head` tag and every pages are tracked (verified by GA Debug on Google Chrome).

I am not sure if someone has already experienced this kind of issue. Do you have any idea of what I could try in order to solve this strange issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply: **Clicks are not the same as Visits**.

According to official [Google explanation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034383?hl=en):

> Google AdWords tracks clicks, while Google Analytics tracks visits. If
>   a user clicks on your ad twice within thirty minutes without closing
>   his or her browser, this is registered by Analytics as one visit to
>   your site, even if the user left your site and then returned shortly
>   after. For example, if a user clicks on your ad once, clicks the back
>   button, and then clicks your ad again, AdWords registers two clicks
>   while Analytics registers one visit.

However your numbers are off quite a bit. Have you review Analytics implementation -- are all the pages being tracked?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Yes I've reviewed every single pages of my Website and those are all tracked. Everything was tested on Google Chrome with the GA Debug plugin.

How can I explain this huge difference between my Adwords clicks and GA visits... Very strange.